# Azure Bastion for Hybrid Cloud Environment

Tags: azure, cloud, vpn, azure-vpn, hybrid-cloud

Is there any way to use Azure Bastion to connect to on-prem systems as well as Azure virtual machines?
I have a hybrid cloud environment where some key machines are on-prem and some are Azure VMs. The Azure VNet is extended with a VPN tunnel so the azure VMs can talk to the on-prem machines.
In Googling my question, I was not able to find much...

- The official page for Azure Bastion describes it as '''Azure Bastion is provisioned directly in your Virtual Network (VNet) and supports all VMs in your Virtual Network (VNet)'''
- This page talks about hybrid envrionments https://blog.ahasayen.com/introducing-azure-bastion/ , saying:
  '''You might also have some sort of hybrid connectivity with your on-premises network and when you are outside the office, you use point to site VPN to securely access your VNET, which is the ideal situation.'"
- I am aware of Azure Arc which is currently in preview. Would something like that be appropriate to make this work?

My overall questions are:

- Am I totally barking up the wrong tree here? Is my understanding off?
- Is it possible to use Azure Bastion to access an on-prem server on an extended VNet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, currently, it's not possible to use Azure Bastion to access an on-prem server on an extended VNet. You only could use Azure Bastion to access all the VMs in the VNet which has AzureBastionSubnet. Refer to [this blog](https://4sysops.com/archives/azure-bastion-overview-and-configuration/)

> Azure Bastion resides on the same virtual network (VNet) as the
>   servers accessed and only connects to one VNet.

Actually, you can have a private and securely RDP/SSH connection between your on-premise server and Azure VM via a VPN gateway, you just can not RDP/SSH on-premise server via Azure portal. If you need this feature with Azure Bastion, it's welcome to give feedback or upvote these similar [feedback1](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/38002603-bastion-supporting-vnet-peering-for-hub-spoke-de) and [feedback2](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/38174800-allow-us-to-access-bastion-via-peers-vpn).

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible via the new capabilities introduced in Azure Bastion Standard Tier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-ip-address

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content a little in textual form. Otherwise, your answer will become unusable if the link changes.